# glsl vertex shader uniform variable not getting activated

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, glm-math

I have been trying to pass a mat4 into VS.
I am activating the shader program before passing the data:

```
renderProg.use();  // glUseProgram( m_programHandle );
glm::mat4 mv = view * model;
renderProg.setUniform("u_ModelViewMatrix", mv);
renderProg.setUniform("u_MVP", projection * mv);
```

But for some reason the uniform variable(**u_ModelViewMatrix**) is not being activated and returning -1 in the "Location" of `glGetUniformLocation`. Here is the VS code:

```
#version 460

layout (location = 0 ) in vec3 VertexPosition;    
uniform mat4 u_MVP;
uniform mat4 u_ModelViewMatrix;

out vec3 Position;    
void main()
{
    vec4 vp = vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
    Position = (u_ModelViewMatrix * vp).xyz;
    gl_Position = u_MVP * vp;
}
```

FS Code:

```
#version 460

in vec3 Position;

uniform vec4 Color;

layout( location = 0 ) out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {
  FragColor = Color;
}
```

Only one uniform is not being able to set "**u_ModelViewMatrix**", the other is being successfully accessed "**u_MVP**". Both uniforms use the same call for receiving data:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &m[0][0]);
```

Right after successful linking and compiling of the Vertex and the Fragment shader , if I am querying the active uniforms , its returning two location of uniforms , one is from FS "**Color**" the other is from VS "**u_MVP**"

```
for( int i = 0; i < nUniforms; ++i ) {
        glGetActiveUniform( m_programHandle, i, maxLen, &written, &size, &type, name );
        location = glGetUniformLocation(m_programHandle, name);
        qDebug() << "Location: " << location << " Name: " << name;
    }
```

Output:
**Location:  0  Name:  Color
Location:  1  Name:  u_MVP**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface variabel `Position` is not used in the fragment shader. So the uniform variable `u_ModelViewMatrix` is not required. This uniform is "optimized out" by the linker and does not become an active program resource. Therefor you'll not get a uniform location for `"u_ModelViewMatrix"`.